# 4069 envelope follower

Tags: cmos, inverting-amplifier

I am trying to build this envelope follower:

[image]

And I haven't been able to get it to work. Without any inpt signal, I'm getting a constant voltage at pin 6 (just before the 1k resistor and LED) and even with an input signal, it stays the same. Can anyone help with this? I can find little information on the circuit so have no troubleshooting leads whatsoever.

FYI: This is for an audio circuit, using an instrument's input to alter PWM on a square wave oscillator

Comment: What is your CMOS p.n.?

Comment: Tried both a 4069 and 4049.

Comment: @TCassa: why on earth does someone want to use a (IC designed as) digital inverter as OpAmp?

Comment: Use opamps, with +-5volt power, and DC-blocked at the input.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect these are very unstable as I recall the phase shift and BW was very supplier sensitive and as suggested already, this old design may no long be guaranteed to work with any supplier and subject to HF oscillations.

So if you have an Op Amp, you are better off with a precision diode  rectifier and control the desired attack time and decay time for your instrument.

### {end edit}

These handy CD4000 series gates work like inverting OP AMPs  where the ratio determines the Analog Voltage Gain , Av=Rf/Ri over a limited range up to 1000 on buffered gates.

If the input is floating then it will just amplify noise.

### Impressions

You didn't  mention the output voltages of each stage, (do so in future).

**I suspect you neglected to AC couple your signal with a suitable cap** that is much lower impedance, Zc(f) than the input Ri.    (33k)

If not sure use a  calculator and if using a polarized cap choose + to input at Vcc/2.

(Zc=1/(2pi*f) with Zc(fmin) < Ri

Stage 1  Av=-2
Stage 2  Av=-100 with rectifier
Stage 3  Av=-1

You must AC couple your signal into the Input since it it is self biased automatically to ~Vcc/2 with the feedback Rf.

Std practice is 0.1uF across Vdd-Vss. (p14-p7) *must have

Comment: I'm thinking back 40 years: only the unbuffered CMOS could be used as linear amplifiers?

Comment: With 9 volts on the 4049, I get 5.5 volts at pin 2, 3 volts at pin 4, and 3 volts at pin 6

Comment: @Transistor Recently was reading data sheets that said 4069 was un-buffered, while 4049 was buffered. The more modern HCU04 is the unbuffered type - they do work as amplifiers with open-loop gain of about 10 to 20.

Comment: @Transistor not from my experience. The (UB) had a gain of 10 and (B)  had a gain of 1k, both worked well.

Comment: @TCassa if output is high then your input is too low ( ie. 0V) MUST use a series cap

Comment: @Tcassa make sure you have 0.1uF on Vdd/Vss

Answer (score 1):

If you use a single polarity supply then of course the circuit produces a positive DC output with no input signal. The inverters try to bias themselves near half the supply voltage but some will be higher and some will be lower.

If you use a dual polarity supply then some ICs with no input signal produce a positive DC output from this circuit, a few produce 0V output and some produce a negative DC output voltage.

The capacitor should charge to the positive peak of the signal if the signal level is correct and the frequency is fairly low.

Comment: Right on @AG  these inverters are single supply referenced to Vcc/2 and not peak detecting from 0V

Answer (score 0):

Measure the output at each gate (particularly the first one) to see if it ever gets off the rail.

I've also heard that process changes (how they're made) may mean that these parts don't work the way they did in 2001.  In the analog region, of course.

Comment: Well, that sucks!